# How to negociate your grade wih prof who is discriminating?

Tags: graduate-school, professorship, grades

I am a grad level student and took my last course this semester. We had several assiged him better since he is advising that student.

What would you do a prof grade you less than what you expected? How should I talk to him?

Comment: "I shared my solution with one of my classmates, he...copied my solution" <-- I would approach this _very_ carefully...

Comment: @cag51, how do you mean exactly?

Comment: Sharing our solution is possibly a violation. You may be lucky to have lost only a few points rather than being accused of misconduct.  Raising the issue may lead to uncomfortable questions.

Comment: @ cag51 did not give him the chance to copy me, just told him how to solve. The copying didnot actually happened.

Comment: Showing you how to solve it could be cheating.

Comment: "I guided him to solve" - the supervisor? Probably you mean your friend?

Comment: This question is one reason why it is always a good idea to mark anonymously.

Comment: Scruffy poorly laid out work that is correct can score less than slightly incorrect work that is neat...

Comment: Sorry, but the last edit makes the question rather unclear and not suitable for a possible reopening.

Answer (score 6):

The rules in your university may differ, but in places where I worked, students typically are expected to trust the professionalism and academic judgement of their lecturers/professors and can not appeal or "negotiate" their mark only because they feel that they deserve a better one. But they can appeal if they believe the assessment procedure was compromised.

If you really want to appeal your results, I'd suggest to submit your appeal following your university procedures. But before you do, check that you understand the meaning of the words that you are using, and how to spell them.

For example, *discrimination* is the unjust or prejudicial treatment of different categories of people, especially on the grounds of race, age, or sex. Assigning random marks is not a discrimination. Favouritism is not a discrimination. Giving other student two marks more is not a discrimination.

Engaging yourself and other students in collusion/plagiarism is likely a violation of the academic conduct / honour code of your university. It appears that you either do not fully understand the rules by which academia and your university live, or do not feel that they apply to you. This is a very poor ground to start throwing accusations against your professor.

Comment: From the post, I understand the prof discriminates against people he does not advise (similar to Prof. Snape from Harry Potter)

Comment: @user111388 Since prof probably chooses the people they advise, this is more accurately described as favouritism, not discrimination. Discrimination is unjust treatment  of different categories, not any groups.